# A-frame play specific animations from sketch fab

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, aframe, webvr

I am creating a scene using A-frame (https://aframe.io).

I am trying to put a `gltf` model of a crow in my scene from [sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/).

The model of the crow from sketchfab has two different animations however - there is a moving pose and a static pose. Since the `gltf` has two different animations built into the model, when I put it into my scene, the model isn't animating because it's on it's default static pose.

How can I get the crow `gltf` model into my scene animated so that is plays the `TakeOff` animation?

Just for clarification, I am looking for a way to specifically reference `TakeOff` animation on the `gltf` model so that instead of the model not animating it should animate the `TakeOf`f animation.  The link to the crow `gltf` model: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/crow-d5a9b0df4da3493688b63ce42c8a83e2

Code to get the `gltf` model into my scene:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-entity gltf-model="https://cdn.glitch.com/a9b3accf-725d-4891-aa13-0786dd661cab%2Fscene%20-%202021-07-01T193347.857.glb?v=1625193238260" position="20 0 -35" rotation="0 90 0" scale="1 1 1" animation-mixer="clip:Take 001; loop:10000000000000000000; timeScale: 1; crossFadeDuration: 1"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `animation-mixer`, you should include [aframe-extras](https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-extras), of which it is a part. You can use their cdn, as you will find in the code below.

The clip you are looking for is called `root|takeOff`, as you will see in the code.

(Also, the code you posted has a different glTF of a wardrode instead of the crow you are looking for; so you should replace `{{YOUR MODEL}}` with the crow.)

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/donmccurdy/aframe-extras@v6.1.1/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-entity gltf-model="{{YOUR MODEL}}" position="20 0 -35" rotation="0 90 0" scale="1 1 1" animation-mixer="clip:root|TakeOff; loop:10000000000000000000; timeScale: 1; crossFadeDuration: 1"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Other animations you can use are `root|LookAround` and `root|Eat`.